# My Syntax Highlighter Died, What Now?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, plugin-syntaxhighlighter

On my wordpress install (hosted by 1&1) a few years back I installed "Syntax Highlighter for WordPress" (I'm currently at 3.0.83.3)

Everything was going great until yesterday when something got updated and now my syntax highlighting doesnt work.  I can see when "view source" that the <pre> tag that is created by my [cpp] tag is immediately closed on the same line instead of waiting for the [/cpp] tag.  It's a bit strange.

Anyways, I went to check if there were updates for the syntax highlighter, and there aren't and it hasnt been updated in 4 years!

I know I could easily switch to another syntax highlighter, but they all seem to use different markup than this one did, and I have a lot of posts I would need to update.

In case it's useful info, I'm using wordpress 4.2.3 and it is at http://blog.demofox.org

Any tips how I could proceed?  Is there any easy way to migrate without having to update every single post that has code on it?  Thanks so much for any help, this is quite an unfortunate thing :/

Comment: I don't see any problem on your blog, can you add explanation on what is not working ?

Comment: I'm so sorry. As often happens, you fight with a problem for a day and then find the solution right after you ask someone else. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this well maintained plugin is a drop in replacement.  I installed this and all is well again.

It's called syntax highlighter evolved.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/

Comment: This `syntaxhighlighter` plugin is from Automattic. You would have used it earlier.

Comment: What do you mean Robert?

Comment: I mean you should have used this plugin instead of the one you were using. Since this plugin is from the company `Automattic` which is behind WordPress, it will never going to run into compatibility issues.

Comment: Sure, but when there are a million plugins that all do the same thing, how do you know which to choose?

I could have spent more time researching it, but I chose instead to pick one and move on so I could get back to researching the topics I write about (:

BTW I had no idea the company that made WP was "Automattic", and didn't even know this specific plugin in the answer was even from a company.

Anyways, yeah... in hindsight I chose a bad one and I was regretting it til I found this one that fits the bill.  Is the lesson that you need to devote a bunch of time to do the right thing in WP?